# How to redirect .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

My old website has 3 url's that lead to same place.

```
http://hemodialysis-krk.com/
http://www.hemodialysis-krk.com/
http://hemodialysis-krk.com/index.php?l=HR
```

I plan delete old website and put new one with totally different url's. Including index.html.
So what would be solution for that situation? 
Should I 301 redirect some off them to index.html? Will first two automaticly link to new index.html file in public_html without redirecting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to redirect all traffic to new site using .htaccess of old sites.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*hemodialysis-krk.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Or create more rules, if you can map sections of pages from old to new site. If you use:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

original path and get query will be used in redirection too. This is always handy working on unique url to reach better position in search engines results.

**EDIT**:
If you need to redirect only urls, which don't exists anymore, then use (not tested):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: My plan is to retain same domain name. I will just replace content of old website with new content. Will this code you wrote then work? I have list of all old url's that I plan to delete and redirect to new one's bacause my new pages will have different names then old one's. Shouldn't adress http://hemodialysis-krk.com/ just link to new index.html file in public_html folder automaticly?